# INNER JOIN en SQL con 4 tablas

Tags: sql

Trato de hacer INNER JOIN en SQL con 4 tablas, pero, no me sale.

Uso este Query SQL (este funciona):

```
SELECT PELICULAS.*, companias.nombre AS nombreCompania
FROM companias INNER JOIN peliculas ON companias.id_compania = peliculas.id_compania
```

Pero, cuando le agrego otro INNER JOIN para entrar la tabla `PELICULAS_DIRECTORES` no funciona:

```
SELECT PELICULAS.*, companias.nombre AS nombreCompania,
DIRECTORES.nombre AS nombreDirector
FROM companias INNER JOIN peliculas ON companias.id_compania = peliculas.id_compania
FROM DIRECTORES INNER JOIN PELICULAS_DIRECTORES ON DIRECTORES.id_director = PELICULAS_DIRECTORES.id_director
```

Diagrama:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El primer Query funciona y me muestra todas las `PELICULAS` y me intercambia el `id_compania` por el `nombre` de la tabla `COMPANIAS`.

Quiero hacer lo mismo y obtener lo mismo, pero ahora, intercambiando el `id_director` de la tabla `PELICULAS_DIRECTORES` por el `nombre` de la tabla `DIRECTORES`. O sea, quiero mostrar al final el `"id", "titulo", "anoLanzamiento", "longitudMinutos", "sinopsis", "nombreCompania", "nombreDirector"`

He probado muchas combinaciones y no me sale, qué tiene mal mi segunda Query?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En una consulta `SELECT` se pone un único `FROM` y ya después los `INNER JOIN` con su respectivo `ON` uniendo los ids de las tablas relacionales. El juntar las tablas sería así:

```
SELECT p.id_pelicula, p.titulo, p.anoLanzamiento, p.longitudMinutos, p.sinopsis, 
c.nombre AS nombreCompania, 
d.nombre as nombreDirector 
FROM PELICULAS_DIRECTORES AS pd
INNER JOIN PELICULAS AS p ON p.id_pelicula = pd.id_pelicula
INNER JOIN DIRECTORES AS d ON d.id_director = pd.id_director
INNER JOIN COMPANIAS AS c ON p.id_compania = c.id_compania;
```

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias por tratar de ayudarme, pero, no me ha funcionado, me da error cuando trato de modificarlo. Quiero mostrar `"id", "titulo", "anoLanzamiento", "longitudMinutos", "sinopsis", "nombreCompania", "nombreDirector"`. Podrías ayudarme un poco mas por favor?. No entiendo por qué ` COMPANIAS` va en el `FROM`, en fin, espero que tengas tiempo y me heches otra mano.

Comment: Creo que no había visto bien el diagrama, disculpa. Al ver que habías puesto 2 from pensaba que el error de la consulta iba por ahí. SELECT * FROM pelicula_director AS pd inner join pelicula as p ON p.id_pelicula = pd.id_pelicula INNER JOIN directores AS d ON d.id_director =pd.id_director     Comprueba que con eso si que unes  las 3 tablas (pelicula_director, director y película). La última tabla compañia no depende de película_director sino de película, investigo y a ver si unimos la última tabla

Comment: Después prueba a añadir la siguiente subconsulta justo después de lo que te he puesto: where p.id_compania =(select * from companias)

Comment: SELECT * FROM pelicula_director AS pd inner join pelicula as p ON p.id_pelicula = pd.id_pelicula INNER JOIN directores AS d ON d.id_director =pd.id_director where p.id_compania =(select * from companias)     Nota: quedaría así, revisa que los nombres de las tablas y los ids son esos

Comment: Usando la última que has puesto, arreglando los nombres y los id's, me sale el siguiente error `Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS`. o.o Ni idea que quiere decir el mensaje... alguna idea?.

Comment: Es por el asterisco que estaba en la subconsulta, dime a ver si funciona, voy a ver lo de exists que es,  estaba comparando un campo con más de uno :SELECT * FROM pelicula_director AS pd inner join pelicula as p ON p.id_pelicula = pd.id_pelicula INNER JOIN directores AS d ON d.id_director =pd.id_director where p.id_compania =(select id_compania from companias)

Comment: Otro error, dice `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression`. o.o.... Si cambiamos el where por este `WHERE p.id_compania = c.id_compania` no funcionaría?.

Comment: También me marca otro error. Por cierto, si elimino el `WHERE` funciona y me salen los atributos de todas las tablas  y solo necesito algunas. Estaba probando y lo he logrado, solo tuve que cambiar el último `WHERE` como te dije antes, por este `WHERE p.id_compania = c.id_compania` y en el `SELECT` indiqué los atributos que quiero, así: `SELECT p.id_pelicula, p.titulo, p.anoLanzamiento, p.longitudMinutos, p.sinopsis, c.nombre AS nombreCompania, d.nombre as nombreDirector`. Funciona genial!, muestra los nombres de `COMPANIAS` y `DIRECTORES` correctamente. No sé cómo funciona, pero, funciona. xD

Comment: Me alegro haberte sido de ayuda :), cambio la solución, por la que hemos descubierto y así si alguien lo encuentra pueda verlo bien

Comment: Seguro que si, gracias por tu ayuda, al final llegamos a una solución. Edita tu respuesta con la solución, más fácil para los demás también.

Comment: Si pudieras añadirle un pequeño up me sería de ayuda, que estoy empezando y cuesta un poco que no lo puntúen como negativo rápidamente :D y sería una motivación para seguir ayudando en lo posible , muchas gracias.

Comment: Seguro, iba a hacerlo, estaba esperando a que editaras la respuesta para elegirte, siempre lo hago, hay que resaltar a la persona que te ayudó siempre.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Mi primer up positivo :D.

Comment: Hola amigo, estaba probando hoy otras cosas y me he dado cuenta que la línea `WHERE p.id_compania = c.id_compania` no es necesaria, el Query funciona perfecta sin esa línea. Esto es debido a que esa línea ya la hemos especificado en `INNER JOIN COMPANIAS AS c ON p.id_compania = c.id_compania`, es decir, estamos repitiendo el mismo requerimiento dos veces en el Query. Si prefieres, puedes borrar la línea del `WHERE` de tu respuesta .

Comment: ok, cambiado,gracias =D